# How to cut/slice a plane mesh into three equal pieces

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have a round mesh plane that I'm trying to divide into three equally-sized and separate meshes. I made a cutting tool using three planes I joined together, which I'm trying to use to perform this operation. What workflow can I use to achieve the result I described?

Using Blender v2.82a.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could just create a curve of type [Sector](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/add_curve/extra_objects.html?highlight=sector) with an angle of $120°$ and duplicate it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you stick to your method you can join the 2 objects into one, go in *Edit* mode, select one of the 2 meshes and go into the *Face panel > Intersect (Knife)*:

[image]

Then remove the planes vertices, select the edges that it has created, press <kbd>V</kbd> to separate.

I guess there are plenty of methods to do what you want, you can also create a single edge and use the *Spin* tool, choose an Angle of 120°. After that duplicate and rotate 120°:

[image]

Or you can start with a single edge and use the *Screw* modifier, then again duplicate and rotate 120°:

[image]

Or you can create a 36 vertex circle, *Fill Type > Triangle Fan*, then select 3 edges and press <kbd>V</kbd> to separate:

[image]

Comment: These are all really great solutions :) thanks for sharing!